# Reusablecode for db operations with dependency injection

Tags: scala

I have multiple actors managing data models that are written to a mongo db.

```
object LevelManager {
  val collectionName = "levels"
}

@Singleton
class LevelManager @Inject()(
                                  val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) extends Actor with ActorLogging  with InjectedActorSupport {

  def collection: Future[JSONCollection] = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection](LevelManager.collectionName))

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg:GetById =>
        var level = collection.flatMap(c => c.find(Json.obj("_id" -> msg.id), Option.empty[JsObject]).one[LevelModel].map {
          result =>
              logger.info( result )
     }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but this db code is used in every actor and i did not manage to have it only once. I'm not sure if this is even a clever way, too. It derived from older scala times without dependency injection, where everything was put in an object trait.

So i'm looking for a trait or something, with basic db io handling

Edit: Before dependency injection i was able to use a trait like this:

```
trait BaseModel[T] {

  val collectionName: String
  val db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db


  def load(id: Long)(implicit fmt: Format[T]) = {
    val coll = db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName)
    coll.find(Json.obj("_id" -> id)).one[T]
  }

  def loadAll()(implicit fmt: Format[T]) = {
    val coll = db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName)
    coll.find(Json.obj()).cursor[T].collect[Vector]()
  }

  def save(id: Long, model: T)(implicit fmt: Format[T]) = {
    val coll = db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName)
    val doc = Json.toJson(model).as[JsObject] + ("_id" -> Json.toJson(id))
    coll.save(doc).map { lastError =>
      if (!lastError.ok) Logger.error(lastError.message)
      lastError.ok
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not keeping it simple? ReactiveMongo is already managing IO and concurrency.

Comment: I'm not happy with having 10 times a similar db query for loading, saving and delete a entry. Ending up with a save, load and delete function without having to use ReactiveMongo queries sounds like "Keeping it simple" to me ;)

Comment: Reinventing actor DB concurrency is definitely not simple, and not the sole way to avoid code duplication ... looks like an x/y question for me

Comment: So having ten times a duplicate code is the best way?

Comment: Please check my edit, maybe this explains more what i'm looking for

Comment: There
Is
No
Need
To
Have
An
Actor
To
Reuse
A
Function

Comment: Sorry that i cannot accept this, so again: I use the db only for basic load and save operations, so this functionality is the same in every actor. So i would like to have a load, loadAll and save function. E.g. this way a junior or trainee never needs to work with the db directly. This is my need. Saying "there is no need" does not help me. If this is bad in any way, please explain **why** exactly, so i can work on a better solution  Thx

Comment: if you don't understand that a common function doesn't need to be implemented as an actor, it's recommended to read more about what's a function and what's the use case for actors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended in creating a trait with **def collection: Future[JSONCollection]** and i'm now able to access the db my favorite db functions. This was my goal and makes life so much better. But i'm unsettled from the recent feedback here, if this has any disadvantages.

```
trait DBStuff[T] {
  def collection: Future[JSONCollection]
  def log: LoggingAdapter

  def save(id: String, model: T)(implicit fmt: Format[T]) = {
    val doc:JsObject = Json.toJson(model).as[JsObject] + ("_id" -> Json.toJson(id))
    collection.flatMap(_.update.one(Json.obj("_id" -> id), doc, true)).map(lastError => if (!lastError.ok) log.warning(s"Mongo LastError: %s".format(lastError)))
  }

  def loadOne(id: String)(implicit fmt: Format[T]): Future[Option[T]] = loadOne( Json.obj("_id" -> id) )

  def loadOne(obj: JsObject, projection:Option[JsObject] = None )(implicit fmt: Format[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {
    collection.flatMap(_.find( obj, projection).one[T].map {
      result =>
        result
    }.recover {
      case err => log.error(s"DB Loading Error: $err")
        None
    })
  }

  def loadAll()(implicit fmt: Format[T]):Future[Vector[T]] = {
    loadAll(Json.obj(), None )
  }

  def loadAll( obj: JsObject, projection:Option[JsObject] = None)(implicit fmt: Format[T]):Future[Vector[T]] = {
    collection.flatMap(_.find(obj, projection ).cursor[T]().collect[Vector](Int.MaxValue, Cursor.FailOnError()).map {
      result => result
    }.recover {
      case err =>
        log.error(s"DB Loading Error: $err")
        Vector.empty
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

```
@Singleton
class TaskManager @Inject()(
                             val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi
                            ) extends Actor with ActorLogging with InjectedActorSupport with DBStuff[TaskModel] {

    def collection: Future[JSONCollection] = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection](TaskManager.collectionName))

    override def preStart() = {

    loadAll() map {
      result =>
        //What ever
    }
}
```